# Start a download in Javascript: does it block bots?

Tags: php, javascript, download, bots

is it true that bots can't run Javascript? I have a download script that first shows an ad and after 5 seconds starts the download. It's in PHP. If I do it in Javascript, will I be able to block bots 100%?

Comment: Stupid bots, yes. Less-stupid bots, no.

Answer (score 2):

No this is not true.  A bot which accesses your website is free to interpret and run Javascript as it sees fit.  It's true that many bots don't execute javascript but there is nothing preventing them from doing so.

There are more standard ways of blocking cooperative bots from following links.

- Robots.txt file: http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html
- Using a meta + nofollow tag

Here's a nice link on the different techniques for working with cooperative bots

- http://www.mattwaite.com/posts/2009/apr/12/telling-google-bot-no/

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.

Long Answer: Most bots do not execute javascript but some do. So: No, this will not be able to block bots 100%.

Comment: Since I count downloads, my goal is to count them as accurate as possible. Bots destroy everything. CAPTCHA is out of discussion, I hate it. Is Javascript the best way?

Comment: In the quick and dirty sense it is, yes. For usability it ain't because some users don't use Javascript as well. No idea how worth your stats are. You need to specify beforehand what's important to you so you can base your decision based on facts rather than on luck.

Answer (score 1):

### No, it won't.

Javascript is a scripting language and is executed clientside. Browsers have javascript engines which can execute javascript, but other engines exist too. Nothing prevents a bot from using a browser, such engines, or implementing (a subset of) one themselves.

If you want to block bots, you should use a captcha.